# find if table locking is disabled

Tags: t-sql

I want to find if table locking is disabled across all tables in all databases.
so I check this property on the index level from sysindexes table or table level?

How can I check it?

Regards
Manjot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, table-level locking cannot be disabled. Page and row locking can be disabled on a per-index basis.

To check that, look in sys.indexes (if on SQL 2005 or above) for the allow_row_locks and allow_page_locks columns.
If on SQL 2000, use the INDEXPROPERTY function to check the IsPageLockDisallowed and IsRowLockDisallowed properties.

SQL 2005:

```
SELECT object_name(object_id), name, index_id, allow_row_locks, allow_page_locks FROM sys.indexes
```

SQL 2000

```
SELECT object_name(id), name, indid, INDEXPROPERTY(id, indid, 'IsPageLockDisallowed') AS IsPageLockDisallowed, INDEXPROPERTY(id, indid, 'IsRowLockDisallowed ') AS IsRowLockDisallowed 
FROM sysindexes
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this old and this may not have applied back then, but you can certainly disable locks at the table level:

SELECT t.name, lock_escalation_desc FROM sys.tables t